# Call a blob data with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a code, and this code call some datas of my MySql database and then show it in a `<p>`, it works perfectly, but when i want to call an image that is saved in a mediumblob type, it does not work.

**Here's the code**

**Ajax.js**

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {
    $("#select").on("change", function(e) {
        var option = $(this).val();
        if(option.toLowerCase() !== "ninguno") { 
            var dataToSend = JSON.parse('{"name": "reference", "value": "'+option+'"}');
            ajaxProcess(dataToSend);
        } else { 
            $("p").each( function() {
                $(this).html("");
            });
        }
    });


    function ajaxProcess(dataToSend) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "process.php", 
            dataType: "json", 
            data: dataToSend, 
            type: "get" 
            }
        )
        .done( function(data) {
            $("#ram").html(data["ram"]);
            $("#camara").html(data["camara"]);
            $("#imagen").html(data["imagen"]); //Here's the problem
        })
        .fail( function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
            console.log("Can´t get the data");
        });
    }
});
```

When i select the value in a combobox, it shows the error message "Can´t get the data"

**Process.php**

```
<?php

$connection = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","labash");
$connection->set_charset("utf8");

if($connection->connect_errno)
    throw new Exception("Error al conectar a la base de datos");

$stmt = $connection->stmt_init();
$query = "SELECT ram,camara,imagen FROM celulares WHERE reference=?";

if($stmt->prepare($query)) { // prepare the sentence
    $name = $_GET["value"];
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $name); //bind data
    $stmt->execute(); // execute the sentence
    $result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the result
    $connection->close();
    echo json_encode($result->fetch_assoc()); // get the data as JSON
}
```

In the html code i call the "ram" data (for example) in a `<p id="ram">` and it works, but the image doesn´t.
Thanks Beforehand

Comment: What is `imagen` on your database.

Comment: You dont want to replace the `html` of an image you will want to replace the `src=""` attribute. So something like `src='data:image/jpeg;base64,<!-- base64 data -->'`

Comment: So something like `$("#imagen").src('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data["imagen"]);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly `imagen` is the name of the column in the database where i save the image

Comment: Yes I know that! What does it contain, a base64 encoded image I would assume

Comment: It doesn´t work
Still show the error message

Comment: ___Error message___ Did you show us the error message in your question??

Comment: Yes, the error message is "Can´t get the data" in the file Ajax.js `.fail( function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
        console.log("Can´t get the data");
    });`

Comment: So that means the PHP failed or was not found

Comment: I guess was not found cause when i erase `imagen` from `$query` in the php file, it  works perfectly... I don´t really know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I solve it

First: I use a [converter Base64](https://www.base64-image.de/) image

Then i copy the code and i save that code in the database

And here´s the new code of the **Ajax.js** file:

```
    $("#imagen").attr('src', data["imagen_encode"]);
```

`imagen_encode` is the new column of my table in the database. i paste all the code of the Base64 converter and save it in the `imagen_encode` column. And i call it in html `<img id="imagen">`